# Regular Expression Quick Query

Tags: python, regex

Quick regular expressions question.

I want an expression that will find the first digit in a line and also a word at the end of that line. (this will exclude any digits in there)

IE if the string is, "12345hello" then I want the regular expression to find "1hello"

Or even if it's "12345hel45667lo" to find the same thing.

I have the first digit down but my expression I thought would work is:

```
print re.findall(r'^\d\D+',string)
```

This just gives me empty brackets, or the first digit if I take out the \D. What gives?

Edit: If I put in a | for or then I get what I want sort of. Returns the words in the string along with the first digit but in separate groupings. I want it all in one.

Comment: What should it return in `1234hel3456lo234a`?

Answer (score 2):

```
print re.findall(r'^\d|\D+',string)

print re.sub(r'(?<!^)\d', '', "12345hel45667lo9a") -> '1helloa'
```

Comment: print str.join('', re.findall(r'^\d|\D+',string))  Since he wants the output a single string, and that splits it on every number, it'll need joining.

Comment: only problem is that we can't join like that, it has to be all in one regex.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can think of is to run a for loop that scans across the string for letters and combines them.